# What is the difference between the "Parsing" tag and the "Reading Comprehension" tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

I feel like these two tags are mostly synonymous.

Both are about understanding a sentence. I agree that "Parsing" is more of an analysis and micro-inspection of which part of the text while "Reading Comprehension" is more about the macro of the text.

However, at the end of the day when its about a language you can't really answer a reading comprehension question without explaining the parts of the sentence, that is unless you just correct the reading error without explaining why it was an error.

So while they may be separate in theory, in practice I don't think you can do reading comprehension without explaining how the text should be parsed.

What are your thoughts on the matter?

Comment: Plenty of reading comprehension errors are the result of some kind of mistake that isn't about parsing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally speaking, parsing is a matter of syntax and comprehension is a matter of semantics. The goal of parsing is to reveal the structure of a phrase and that of comprehension is to understand its meaning.

I guess there are borderline cases (e.g. parsing combined particles is more or less understanding their meaning), but they should be different enough.